# Comparison of the spectrum decomposition

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sp.spectral-theory

In the spectral theorem, we learned that the spectrum of a linear operator $A$ is a disjoint union of: point spectrum (eigenvalues), continuous spectrum (the kernel of $zI-A$ is zero, the closure of $\rm Ran(zI-A)$ is the whole space but the resolvent is unbounded), and the residue spectrum (the closure of ${\rm Ran}(zI-A)$ is not the whole space). We will call this the first way of decomposition.

By the spectral theorem of self-adjoint operators (on Hilbert spaces), we also know that the spectrum of a self-adjoint operator $A$ can be decomposed into pure point spectrum (which is eigenvalues, by the definition from the book of Reed-Simon), the absolutely continuous spectrum and the singular continuous spectrum. It is remarked in the book of Reed-Simon that, in general, the union of these three sets is not the spectrum of $A$.

My question is: for a self-adjoint operator $A$, we already know that its residue spectrum is empty, its continuous spectrum is the union of the singular continuous spectrum and the absolutely continuous spectrum. Therefore, why the union of pure point spectrum, the singular continuous spectrum and the absolutely continuous spectrum is not the spectrum of $A$? Maybe the point spectrum is not just the point spectrum in the first way of decomposition?

Comment: Something seems to be wrong with the first paragraph: the point spectrum and the residual spectrum are certainly not disjoint, in general (for instance, in finite dimensions they even coincide).

Comment: By the way, may I suggest to you to add an explicit reference to the claim that you cite from Reed-Simon? For instance, in which book (there are four of them!) and on which page there can we find this claim?

Comment: The issue is simply that the set of eigenvalues (what you call the *point spectrum*) need not be closed. The spectrum always is the closure of the set of eigenvalues (in fact, many people including Simon in other writings and, for what it's worth, myself define $\sigma_{pp}$ in this way), plus the sc spectrum, plus the ac spectrum. I suspect what you got confused about is this discrepancy (is $\sigma_{pp}$ defined as just the eigenvalues, or [better, I think] as the closure of this set?).

Comment: I think it is just a matter of definition. The point spectrum is defined as those z such that Ker(zI-A) is non-empty (thus eigenvalues). The residue spectrum is defined for those z such that Ker(zI-A) is empty but the closure of the range of (zI-A) is not the whole space. By this definition, the point spectrum set and the residue spectrum set are for sure disjoint.

Comment: Yes, it is just a matter of definition. It seems to me that the union of ac spectrum and sc spectrum is not the ``continuous'' spectrum as in the first manner of decomposition. My precise reference is: For the point spectrum \sigma_p(A), page 188, section VI 3 of the book of Reed-Simon (Vol I). For the purely point spectrum \sigma_{pp}(A), I refer to Page 231, section VII 2 (Vol I) of the book of Reed-Simon.